# Why laravel inserts "0" instead of "NULL" in mysql database?

Tags: php, laravel

Why do i have different behaviour for following code?

```
\DB::table('Test')->insert(
    array(
        'NullableInt' => "NULL", // gives 0
        'NullableVarchar' => "NULL" // gives NULL
    )
);
```

I need to parse csv file to seed a table. fgetcsv parses everything as string, for text/varchar fields "NULL" as string works, for integer - not. Why?

Comment: try `null` as in PHP's actual null type and not as a string? The fact its a string probably means at some point in the chain its cast to an int which results in 0 and not null.

Comment: @Wader yes, `null` (non-string) works. I am interested in this behaviour. Is this a bug? Or why does laravel does that?

Comment: @avasin as with all non-strictly typed languages type juggling becomes a pain at some point. In PHP when you cast a string to an int you'll likely get 0 or at least a number which PHP has attempted to extrapolate out of the string. When you cast `"NULL"` to an int, thus you get 0.

Comment: Agreed. But laravel's developers are quite experienced people, i believe they have thought about that. Just interested why does it work this way. BTW, seems that mysql converts "NULL" string to NULL itself.

Comment: Always difficult to predict how those types of things will behave in non-strictly typed languages. Best to be as specific with types as possible to avoid unpredicted/desired behaviour. Taylor is quite the fan of the `in_null()` function which strictly looks for `null` which is possibly where this behaviour is coming from.

Comment: It's not a bug. `"NULL"` is a string, `NULL` is not.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that MySQL sets text/varchar field as NULL, when you try to write there "NULL" (string) value.

When you will try to write "NULL" string to int field in mysql client directly, you will get zero.

Answer (score 1):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/type-conversion.html

When inserting a string into a numeric column, it will be cast to an integer automatically.

```
mysql> SELECT CAST('NULL' AS UNSIGNED INTEGER)
        -> 0

mysql> SELECT CAST(NULL AS UNSIGNED INTEGER)
        -> NULL
```

More interesting cases:

```
mysql> SELECT CAST('1NULL' AS UNSIGNED INTEGER)
        -> 1

mysql> SELECT CAST('NULL1' AS UNSIGNED INTEGER)
        -> 0

mysql> SELECT CAST('1,000' AS UNSIGNED INTEGER)
        -> 1
```

If you want null, you should do either PHP's `null` or `DB::raw('NULL')` (which prevents Laravel from treating it as the string you provided it as):

```
\DB::table('Test')->insert(
    array(
        'NullableInt' => null,
        'NullableVarchar' => DB::raw('NULL'),
    )
);
```